# Quartz.net job to start daily at given time with millisecond interval

Tags: quartz.net

I'm trying out Quartz.net, which would possibly solve an issue of mine. However I can not seem to find a way to start a job at a given time of day (07:30) to run a number of times (1000) with a interval in milliseconds (1).

I've tried a CronSchedule, but intervals can not be set. With SimpleSchedule, a start time can not be set and with DailyTimeIntervalSchedule I can not set interval in milliseconds. I've also tried to combine a setup with the varoius with the fluent api, to no avale.

Is what I try to achieve actually not possible in Quartz.net?

Comment: Do you really want to run the job 1000 times in one second at the millisecond interval? Did you try a test to see if Quartz.net can execute jobs at this rate?

Comment: I assume it can, since it's doable to set the interval in milliseconds with the SimpleScheduele, but I've not benchmarked it or anything to see the acctual performance. 

It's for a "simple" load test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are after:

```
IJobDetail theJobToRun = JobBuilder.Create<NoOpJob>().Build();
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                        .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(7, 30, 0))
                        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                                        .WithInterval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))
                                        .WithRepeatCount(999))
                        .ForJob(theJobToRun)
                        .Build();
```

Just as sgmoore noted, you might not get millisecond precision as your thread pool will be saturated with jobs and it all depends how much work they true. Quartz.NET infrastructure will also take its own time watching for fire times and instantiating jobs.

Comment: Shouldn't that be .WithRepeatCount(999) ?

Comment: That solved it. Thanks Marko Lahma
@sgmoore, your right 999 for one thousand executions. Thanks to you as well!

Comment: I don't know if the old version of Quartz support it or not, but the newer version (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.1-SNAPSHOT/index.html) DateBuilder.DateOf api: Get a Date object that represents the given time, on today's date (equivalent to todayAt(int, int, int)). Thus is just run for today, but not daily. So it's wrong!